# Embed ruby within URL : Middleman Blog

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, middleman

I am having some problem with some facebook share link on Middleman blog:-

Well I have :

```
<%= link_to current_article, article %>
```

=> `<a href="http://0.0.0.0:4567/link_of_article">Article Title</a>`

I am trying to have:-

```
<a class ="btn btn-primary" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://0.0.0.0:4567/link_to_title&text=Title of the Article Here" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook">Facebook Share</i></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + article_url(article, :text => article.title), :class => "btn btn-primary" do %>
  <i class="fa fa-facebook">
    Facebook Share 
  </i>
<%end%>
```

I am assuming that `current_article_url` is `http://0.0.0.0:4567/link_to_title`